# Replace characters in HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have some text on a page which I get using a variable:

```
<p class="category-list-replace">ksadj| lksd| sakdj</p> 
<p class="category-list-replace">sdawfe| nekesa</p> 
<p class="category-list-replace">opeiuf| elnfele</p> 

var list = $('.category-list-replace');
```

The text is in three different parts, so the variable returns 3 objects. I want to replace any instance of a pipe; "|" with a comma "," instead.

```
var listnew = list.replace("|", ",");
```

I'm stuck here though and can't work out how to split the variables so each one can have the character replaced.

Comment: how about working with them as arrays and deal with each string on iterating

Comment: @p.s.w.g I've updated the example with pipes, and I would like to replace the text please

Comment: the answer below must do you good i trust

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend using the [`text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function, for example:

```
var list = $('.category-list-replace');
list.text(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace(/\|/g, ",")
});
```

Note this also uses a regular expression (`/\|/`)  with a global flag (`g`) to replace multiple occurrences of the `|` character.

```js
$("#go").click(function() {
  var list = $('.category-list-replace');
  list.text(function(i, text) {
    return text.replace(/\|/g, ",")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="category-list-replace">ksadj| lksd| sakdj</p> 
<p class="category-list-replace">sdawfe| nekesa</p> 
<p class="category-list-replace">opeiuf| elnfele</p>
<button id="go">Replace</go>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you're looking for?

```
list.each(function() {
  var $element = $(this);
  var text = $element.text();
  $element.text(text.replace('|', ','));
});
```

Comment: for `var list` he must initialise it like `var list = $('*.category-list-replace')` so that it picks them all, the previous might pick the first occurance only, i once had that problem not `var list = $('.category-list-replace')`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's 3 html dom with a class named "category-list-replace"

```
lists = document.getElementsByClassName("category-list-replace")
var results = [];
for(i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
var contents = lists[i].innerHTML;
var texts = contents.split("|");
texts = texts.join(",");
results[i] = texts;
}
```

check the results array!